# How to find Office Apps (Excel, Word, OneNote, Planner) usage in O365?

Tags: office-365

I understand we have Usage reports available in the O365 Reports section. These reports provide usage for SharePoint, Exchange and OneDrive only.
Is there any way, by which we can track the usage of apps like Word, Excel, OneNote, Planner, etc.?
We are trying to find the adoption rate of these Apps throughout the organization. I have checked PnP PowerShell, Graph API but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

This information isn't tracked by Microsoft at this time -- I'm not aware of any plans for them to track this information, either.